# How to list elements of a table in a knitr document

Tags: r, knitr, kable

I'm wondering how to refer to the percentages or frequencies from certain cells of a table in a knitr document. Here is an example of a table I might have:

```
library(dplyr)

Tab <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(
    NewVar = scales::percent(length(carb) / nrow(.))
  )
kable(Tab, format = "html")
```

Now let's say I want to refer to a specific element of that table in the document text. One option is to write a conditional filter as follows:

```
scales::percent(mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% filter(cyl == 8) %>% nrow(.) / mtcars %>% nrow(.))
```

Before compiling, the knitr text would look like this:

"Of all the cars in the dataset, `r scales::percent(mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% filter(cyl == 8) %>% nrow(.) / mtcars %>% nrow(.))` have eight cylinders."

That works for simpler examples. What about when there are a number of filters or group_by's? Do you have additional techniques for referring to particular elements of a table? I'm interested in both dplyr and non-dplyr techniques.